# Converting a Binary Tree into a Singly Link list

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, c++14, binary-search-tree

I am trying to convert a **binary tree into a Singly linked list**.I am trying to solve the problem in **O(n) time complexity**.To achieve O(n) time complexity I am **returning both head and tail of the link list**.I am getting Wrong output please help me out.

**Approach 1 is Working correctly.To reduce time complexity of Approach 1. I need to remove the while loop which is being used to traverse left link list.Therefore I need to return both Head and Tail pointer of the Link list.**
*Both Approach are Recursive in nature.*

```
/**************** To Construct LL from a BST ***************/

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "BinaryTreeNode.h"
#include "linklist_class.cpp"
#include <queue>

void printTreeLevelWise(BinaryTreeNode<int>* root){
    if(root == NULL){       //Base case
        return;
    }
    queue<BinaryTreeNode<int>*> pendingNodes;
    pendingNodes.push(root);
    while(pendingNodes.size() != 0){
        BinaryTreeNode<int>* front = pendingNodes.front();
        pendingNodes.pop();
        cout<<front->data<<":";
        if(front->left != NULL){
            cout<<"L"<<front->left->data;
            pendingNodes.push(front->left);
        }
        if(front->right != NULL){
            cout<<"R"<<front->right->data;
            pendingNodes.push(front->right);
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    
}

BinaryTreeNode<int>* takeInputLevelWise(){
    int rootData;
    cout<<"Enter root data"<<endl;
    cin>>rootData;
    if(rootData == -1){
        return NULL;
    }
    BinaryTreeNode<int>* root = new BinaryTreeNode<int>(rootData);
    queue<BinaryTreeNode<int>*> pendingNodes;
    pendingNodes.push(root);
    
    while(pendingNodes.size() != 0){
        BinaryTreeNode<int>* front = pendingNodes.front();
        pendingNodes.pop();
        
        cout<<"Enter Left Child of "<<front->data<<endl;
        int leftChildData;
        cin>>leftChildData;
        if(leftChildData != -1){
                BinaryTreeNode<int>* child = new BinaryTreeNode<int>(leftChildData);
                front->left = child;
                pendingNodes.push(child);
        }
        
        cout<<"Enter right Child of "<<front->data<<endl;
        int rightChildData;
        cin>>rightChildData;
        if(rightChildData != -1){
                BinaryTreeNode<int>* child = new BinaryTreeNode<int>(rightChildData);
                front->right = child;
                pendingNodes.push(child);
        }
        
    }
    return root; 
}
/******* To print Link list  *********/
void print(node *head){            
    while(head != NULL){         
        cout<<head ->data<<" ";
        head = head->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

/***************************** Approach1 ******************************/
/* Working Correctly */

node* LLfromBST(BinaryTreeNode<int>* root){
    if(root == NULL){
        return NULL;
    }
    node* lhead = LLfromBST(root->left);
    node* rhead = LLfromBST(root->right);
    node* newNode = new node(root->data);
    
    
    newNode->next = rhead;
    
    // lhead head is NULL Then we will try to access NULL->next
    // to stop this let's put a check
    if(!lhead){           
        return newNode;
    }
    
    node* temp = lhead ;    
    while(temp->next != NULL){
        temp = temp->next;
    } 
    temp->next = newNode;
    
    return lhead;
}


/***************************** Approach2 ******************************/
/* Not Working */
//O(n)  //head = p.first and tail = p.second

pair<node*,node*> LLfromBST2(BinaryTreeNode<int>* root){
    if(root == NULL){
        pair<node*,node*> p ;
        p.first = NULL;
        p.second = NULL;
        return p;
    }
    pair<node*,node*> lp  = LLfromBST2(root->left);
    pair<node*,node*> rp  = LLfromBST2(root->right);
    
    node* newNode = new node(root->data);
    newNode->next = rp.first;   
    
    // lhead head is NULL Then we will try to access NULL->next
    // to stop this let's put a check
    if(!lp.first){        
        pair <node*,node*> p;
        p.first = newNode;
        p.second = rp.second;
        return p;
    }
    lp.second->next = newNode;
    pair <node*,node*> p;
    p.first = lp.first;
    p.second = rp.second;
    return p;
}


int main(){
    // BST :   4 2 6 1 3 5 7 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1
    
    BinaryTreeNode<int>* root = takeInputLevelWise();
    printTreeLevelWise(root);
    cout<<endl;
    //Approach 1
    /*node* head = LLfromBST(root);
    print(head);
    cout<<endl;*/
    //Approach 2
    node* head2 = LLfromBST2(root).first;
    print(head2);
    delete root;
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mre] that would be runnable and demonstrate the wrong output. If you are asking me to complete your program into something compilable and then try to figure out for which inputs it does something that violates your expectations somehow, I'd rather do something else to be honest...

Comment: okay I have uploaded the  complete runnable code now.

Answer (score 1):

Just an inorder traversal of BST will yield a sorted list of the nodes. So you need something like below:

```
        void buildLLFromBST(BinaryTreeNode<int>* root, ListNode<int>* node) {
            if (root) {
               buildLLFromBST(root->left, node);
               node->next = root;
               node = node->next;
               buildLLFromBST(root->right, node);
            }
        }
```

and you could call it like : `buildLLFromBST(root, dummynode)`

Comment: I know that approach . But What is the Problem in my approach ?

Comment: @jaypratap: You do know that inorder traversal is O(n), right?

Comment: @jaypratap It is hard to understand your approach from code, why do you need left pointer and right pointer?

Comment: Please refer to the Approach 1. Approach 1 is Working correctly.To reduce time complexity of Approach 1. I need to remove the while loop which is being used to traverse left link list.Therefore I need to return both Head and Tail pointer of the Link list.